# c# Covariance Generics on Properties / Generic Access?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, downcast

```
public interface IFoo { }
public abstract class IFooDerived : IFoo { }
public class Foo : IFooDerived { }

public interface IBar { }
public abstract class IBarDerived : IBar { }
public class Bar : IBarDerived { }

public interface IExample<out A, B> where A : IFoo where B : IBar
{
    A Foo(B b);
}

public class Example : IExample<Foo, Bar>
{
    static Example example = new Example();
    static Example()
    {
        Example ex = example;

        IExample<IFoo, IBar> ex_huh = ex; //How can I do this?

        //Or is there a way where I can say I don't care, but I still want to reference ex, like this:
        IExample<object,object> ex_huh2 = ex;
        //Or:
        IExample<, > ex_huh2 = ex;

        ex_huh2.Foo(new Bar()); //And still call Foo?
    }

    public Foo Foo(Bar b)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In the above example, how do I downcast and reference the static example variable without knowing its generic types but still be able to call "A Foo(B b)"?

Is there a strongly typed way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IExample<IFoo, IBar> ex_huh = ex; //How can I do this?
```

You can't, because it would break type safety. And that's because you're trying to make your method's parameter type (that parameter to `Foo(B b)`) more general, and that's not safe.

To make it easier to see why that's a problem, let's boil your example down to something equivalent (as far as that method parameter goes):

```
function DoSomethingWithFoo(Foo foo) { ... }
// The following line won't compile, but let's pretend it does and see what happens
Action<IFoo> doSomethingWithIFoo = DoSomethingWithFoo;
doSomethingWithIFoo(new OtherFoo());
```

where `OtherFoo` is some other class that implements `IFoo`, but does not descend from the `Foo` class.

Whoops! You're calling `DoSomethingWithFoo`, which expects an instance of `Foo`, but passing an `OtherFoo` instead! Wacky hijinks ensue.

That's essentially what you're trying to do in your example. You're trying to take a class with a method that expects a parameter of the `Foo` type, and cast that to something that lets you pass any `IFoo` instead.

(And that's why the compiler won't let you declare `IExample`'s `B` type parameter as `out B`, which is what it would have to be to let you cast an `IExample<..., Foo>` to an `IExample<..., IFoo>`. The compiler sees that the `B` type parameter is used as the type of a method parameter, and that therefore, making it covariant would break type safety.)

---

As for how to accomplish what you're looking for: that's going to depend. Your specific example of wanting to do

```
IExample<...figure out how to declare this...> = ...any IExample<A, B>...;
ex_huh2.Foo(new Bar());
```

isn't going to work in general, because that "...any `IExample<A, B>`..." might well be an `IExample<..., OtherBar>`, and then you can't pass it a `new Bar()`. You'll have to figure out how you want to resolve that conflict.

Maybe you really do want to pass in a `new Bar()`, in which case maybe you want to do that inside a method that's constrained to only taking `IExample`s with `Bar` as their second type parameter:

```
public void AddABar<TFoo>(IExample<TFoo, Bar> example)
{
    example.Foo(new Bar());
}
```

Or maybe you want to create a new instance of whatever the second type parameter is:

```
public void AddAThing<TFoo, TBar>(IExample<TFoo, TBar> example)
    where TBar : new()
{
    example.Foo(new TBar());
}
```

Or maybe you want to make `IExample<A, B>` descend from a non-generic `IExample` that declares a non-generic `Foo(IBar b)`, implement that non-generic method on your `Example` class, and do a typecast to `B` inside that method -- taking the risk that if you pass the wrong type into that method at runtime, you'll get an `InvalidCastException`.

It really all comes down to how you want to resolve that conflict of "I want to cast this to something I can pass a `new Bar()` to", when in point of fact any given implementation of `IExample<A, B>` won't necessarily be able to accept a `new Bar()` as a method parameter.